# How to load or show images based on device density in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I want to show image same as splash screen image. I want to know how to get same splash screen using javascript, phonegap config.xml file values.

I saw example phonegap project files and www containing one config.xml file having icon, splash screen images mapped based on density. How to access icon, splash image based on device density.

[Please see sample config.xml file](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml)

And I want how to get defined app splash screen for each platform

Comment: Which platform ? Android IOS or ???

Comment: I want know about Android OS related thinks only.